# create django user who can not login

Tags: python, django, django-users

I want to create a user whom I'm using as a *ForeignKey* and i don't want those users can login to system. I have no idea how to go on. (about setting [set_unusable_password()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password) or None, and how to perform it):

my **accounts.py** file is as

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    GENDER = (("MALE", "Male"), ("FEMALE", "Female"))
    
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Types.choices, default=Types.PATIENT)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=GENDER)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "phone"  # username
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()
```

thanks in advance guys. <3

Comment: If they should not be able to log in, why do you use `AbstractBaseUser` as base class? You could use `models.Model` instead. If your default User model cannot log in, the Django admin app can't be used.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [is_active](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/) field of the user record

> **is_active Boolean**. Designates whether this user account should be
> considered active. We recommend that you set this flag to False
> instead of deleting accounts; that way, if your applications have any
> foreign keys to users, the foreign keys won’t break.

Comment: thanks for replay, I've override the django default user model and I've `active` boolean field in my model too, but doesn't work as expected.(Im new to django:)

Answer (score 1):

In View you should also check whether the user is active or not.
For Eg:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username = username,password = password)
        if user is not None and user.active:
            login(request,user)
```

As you have overide your user model and changed active field from is_active.If active field is False then it will not allow the user to log in if the user is active it will allow user to log in.